# i am getting Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;

while(t--)
{
    ll n, a[10000000];
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        int flag=0;
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[i])
            {
                cout<<a[j]<<" ";
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag==0)
         cout<<"-1 ";
}
cout<<"-1\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

why i am getting segmentation fault using this code? is there anything wrong in the code. as per my knowledge there is nothing wrong in code. please do explain the fault...

Comment: `a[10000000]` too big

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Unrelated to your segmentation fault (which is absolutely _full_ of information you can examine in a debugger), there is at least one thing wrong in your code: don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`, it's an internal implementation detail.

Comment: if you ever plan to write code professionally please avoid the first three lines of your code.

Comment: I get that there are a lot of bad tutorials online that propagate `using namespace std;` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` but I don't understand why I keep seeing `#define ll long long`.

Comment: I expect this is a competitive programming problem.

Comment: @drescherjm yes! so i have used those short hands to save time. but i could see majority of comments suggesting to avoid this practice.....

Comment: I use `int64_t` when I need a 64 bit integer at work. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Interesting thing about using shortcuts to save time: Proving that they are indeed shortcuts can take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

`a[10000000]` is probably too large to have automatic storage duration. Regard something of the order of 1Mb as the limit.

The fix is to replace the first two lines of your loop with

```
std::size_t n; // using a macro is a bad idea
std::cin >> n; // no professional programmer uses `using namespace std`
std::vector<long long/*using a macro is a bad idea*/> a(n);
```

noting that you ought to deal with any exceptions to the `std::vector` construction if `n` is too large.

Comment: `a(10000000);` should be moved to be after the input of `n` and then just use `a(n);`

Comment: @NathanOliver ya. that would be executed at run time.